A linear optimization with non-linear constraints
Given an entry-wisely nonnegative matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{N \times N}$, with $M_{jj}=0,~ \forall j\in [N]$. Also, $M$ has all its non-diagonal elements strictly positive. And some (non-diagonal) entries of $M$ may be $+\infty$. Finally, let $K$ be some given integer with $1\leq K \leq N$.
With that said, I want to optimize the inner product between $M$ and our variable matrix $Q$, $\text{Tr}(M^TQ)$. Where $Q$ has some strange constraints:

$Q$ are of the form: $Q=\begin{pmatrix} q_1 & q_2 & ... & q_N \end{pmatrix}$ with $q_j \in \{0,1\}^{N}$. And $\sum_jq_j = \boldsymbol{1}$, which is the all-one vector.
There are at most $K$ columns of $Q$ are nonzero, and other $N-K$ columns of $Q$ are all-zero vectors.

It can be regarded that those $K$ nonzero $q_i's$ are indicator vectors of a way to partition $[N]$ into $K$ parts.
The following are some of my ideas:

Trivially, to avoid the objective being $\infty$, as long as $M_{ij}=\infty$, we must put $Q_{ij}=0$.
The problem is NP-hard. Towards this, notice that when we allow $M$ to contain $\infty$ values, then the problem is NP-hard. Since we are trying to find a vertex cover set $S=\{i|q_i \neq \boldsymbol{0}\}$ with $|S|=K$, this can be seen by mapping instances of vertex cover to the mentioned problem by letting $M \gets A(G)$ (adjacency matrix of the graph), and replace the zero entries of $M$ to $\infty$.
Also, even if we do not allow $\infty$ to appear in matrix $Q$, the problem is still NP-hard. One can again map instances of vertex cover to the mentioned problem by letting $M \gets A(G)$ (adjacency matrix of the graph), and replace the zero entries of $M$ to $N+1$, where $N$ is the number of total nodes. If the result is $=N-K$ then there exists a vertex cover $S, |S|=K$ in $G$. If the result $>N-K$, then the original instance mapped is a no instance.
If $q_i \neq \boldsymbol{0}$, then $Q_{ii}=(q_i)_i=1$.
If we are able to formulate the convex hull, say $C$, of all such $Q$'s. Then we can run
$$\min \text{Tr}(M^T Q) \\ \text{subject to } Q \in C.$$
We will eventually get some $Q^* \in C$. And if we can further decompose $Q^*$ as convex combination of $Q_1,...,Q_m$ satisfying the two constraints on above. Then we can evaluate the objective values given by $Q_1,Q_2,...,Q_m$. There must be some one attaining the same value as $Q^*$'s. Because the objective function is linear, hence there must be some "vertex of the polytope" being an optimal solution.

I also want to call for reasonable relaxations if we cannot solve the strict, hard problem itself, which is very likely to be the case. Any related materials or ideas are welcome. Thank you very much!

This is an integer program - not too strange actually.  To formulate your second constraint, you can add variables $c_1, \ldots, c_N$ with $c_j \in {0,1}$ and the constraints $\sum_j c_j \leq K$, $Q_{ij} \leq c_j$.

This can be formulated as an instance of integer linear programming, so you can solve it with any off-the-shelf ILP solver (e.g., CPLEX, Gurobi).
If this is NP-hard, there is no better algorithm/approach.

I also want to call for reasonable relaxations, if we cannot solve the strict, hard problem itself.
